# Prove that for any $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)=x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

[image]

### Attempt.

I was trying to argue by contradiction. Say there is a $x_0 \in [0,1]$ so that $f(x_0) \neq x_0$. WLOG, assume $f(x_0) < x_0$. Now, notice that $f \circ f$ is the inverse of $f$ by definition. so $f$ has to be monotonic. (increasing or decreasing).

Assume it is decreasing. That is, if $a<b \implies f(a) > f(b)$.

Now, we know there is some $\alpha \in [0,1]$ so that $f(\alpha) = \alpha $. No WLOG assume $\alpha > x_0$, then

$$ f(\alpha) < f(x_0) \implies \alpha < f(x_0) < x_0$$

This is a contradiction.

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: Your assumption that $f$ is decreasing is a little risky, given that $f(1) > f(0)$.

Comment: When you already have two points $\alpha$ , namely 0 and 1, with $f(\alpha)=\alpha$ saying there exists $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$ is making things unnecessarily complicated right$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim.** $f$ is strictly increasing. (I thought it is trivial but you all doubt it. Little confused.)

**Proof.** If not, say $x_1>x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$, then since $f(0)\leq f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)\leq f(1)$, by intermediate value theorem of continuous function, we can find $\xi\in(0,x_2]$ such that $f(\xi)=f(x_1)$, therefore
$$
f\circ f\circ f(\xi)=f\circ f\circ f(x_1),
$$
destroying the condition $f\circ f\circ f(x)=x$. $\square$

Then, suppose there is $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $x_0>f(x_0)$, then we have
$$
x_0>f(x_0)>f(f(x_0))>f(f(f(x_0))),
$$
contradictory. $x_0<f(x_0)$ likewise.

Comment: Why $f$ must be strictly increasing? It isnt given.

Comment: Given $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Impossible for decreasing.

Comment: counterexample: $f(x)=\sin(\frac52\pi x)$...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Your $f$ has $f(f(f(1/5)))=1$. How could?

Comment: I'm saying that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ does **not** imply that $f$ is strictly increasing, even if it is smooth. You need to argue **why** it is strictly increasing.

Comment: ...I think it is clear in the problem statement. 'notice that $f\circ f$ is the inverse of $f$ by definition. so $f$ has to be monotonic.'

Comment: $f \circ f \circ f = Id$ implies $f$ is bijection. Bijection and continuous implies strictly monotonic.